# Increase speed of query on PostgreSQL JSONB column containing billions of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have single JSONB column in a table, which looks like - `{key_x: value_x}`. The table contains billions of rows. 
I am querying for value in it using -
`SELECT data->> some_key FROM tableName WHERE data ? some_key;`
I have used `GIN` index on the column, used query-
`CREATE INDEX data_index ON tableName USING  GIN (data)`)`
I have to use a lot of these queries, and at present, it is taking too much time.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT data->> 'somekey' FROM tableName WHERE data ? 'some_key';
```

returns-

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on homeshubhgoethereumagethchaindata  (cost=0.00..1885.42 rows=39 width=32) (actual time=1.911..15.488 rows=545 loops=1)
   Filter: (data ? 'c2VjdXJlLWtleS3GJ+NCu6KAcCJRTC1SLiK6ZvkRZT0avMdL0KeGitPLNg=='::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 37748
   Buffers: shared hit=1397
 Planning time: 3.574 ms
 Execution time: 121.253 ms
```

The number of rows is supposed to increase in future. Is there some way to increase the speed of query?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create index` statement and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: A tenth of a millisecond (0.000138 seconds) sounds pretty fast to me. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: Above query plan is when a number of rows are very less(1200 in this case), as the number of rows increases, the execution time also increases(3.833ms when the number of rows = 26000) and keeps on increasing with the number of rows.

Comment: Then show us the **real** plan where things are too slow.

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it looks like you have single key-value record in jsonb column, not array. If so, did you consider to replace this jsonb with two regular columns with B-tree index? This will work much faster than GIN-index on whole json data.

Or in case if this jsonb is required, you can keep it, just add regular column for key field and use it for searching. Sure, it means data duplication, but on the other hand you will get speed gain.

**UPD**. You can convert json to columns with the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName 
    ADD COLUMN "key"   VARCHAR,
    ADD COLUMN "value" VARCHAR;

UPDATE tableName SET 
    key = (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(data)),
    value = json ->> (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use specific functional index on jsonb column (not GIN):
Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tableName((data->>'some_key'));
```

Comment: Actually, the key is not constant, for every entry there is a different key.

Comment: "I would not state that this confidently" - If that is against my comment, then - Yes, I'm sure every key is unique.
This is how data in a row looks- `{"ZGJVcGdyYWRlXzIwMTcwNzE0ZGVkdXBsaWNhdGVEYXRh": "Kg=="}`

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary no - it was for the answer - I totally disagree with it, but it stated with such confidence :)